# Hyper-V error. Running Windows Phone Emulator and VM in the same time (Windows 8)

Tags: linux, windows, windows-phone-8, emulation

I'm developling a WP8 application on my computer (OS : Windows 8).
I need to install a VM to have linux.
In the same time i need to use my Emulator of Windows Phone.

I downloaded VMWare and create a virtual machine, but i had this error :

```
VMware Workstation and Hyper-V are not compatible. Remove the Hyper-V role
from the system before running VMware Workstation.
```

I can't remove the Hyper-V because i need it, to use the Emulator of Windows Phone.

Maybe i didn't search well , but i only found solutions who will make me cut my Hyper-V. So it will not be possible to use my Emulator and my VM in the same time.

So, my question is : Is it possible to use my Emulator Windows Phone and in the same time to have a VM with linux who is running ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. You have two ways:

1) Install your [Linux into Hyper-V](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/5078-hyper-v-create-linux-virtual-machine-windows-8-a.html)

2) Turn Off Hyper-V, restart Windows, Use VMware. Then turn on Hyper-V, restart and use Windows Phone Emulator.

You can turn on or off Hyper-V from command line:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```